# How I can replace user id to username in django JSON?

Tags: django, json

I'm writing a simple chat with ajax and I have a problem with JSON. I need `username` instead of  `id`.

JSON seems like:

```
[{"pk": 41, "model": "chat.post", "fields": {"timestamp": "2012-01-27 22:14:46", "user": 1, "text": "weq"}}]`
```

I need replace `"user": 1` to `"user": username`.

How I can do it?

**My model:**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Post(models.Model):
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        text = models.TextField()
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-id']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return "[%s] %s by user: %s" % (
                self.timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                self.text,
                self.user
            )
```

**My view:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from live.chat.models import Post

@login_required
def updates_after(request, id):
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Type'] = "text/javascript"
    response.write(serializers.serialize("json",
        Post.objects.filter(pk__gt=id)))
    # __gt - greaten then > id
    return response

@login_required
def saymessage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if "text" in request.POST:
            text = request.POST["text"]
            user = request.user
            message = Post()
            message.user, message.text = user, text
            message.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        pass
```

JSON response example:
[
  {
    "pk": 42, 
    "model": "chat.post", 
    "fields": {
      "timestamp": "2012-01-28 18:08:44", 
      "user": 1, 
      "text": "dasd"
    }
  }
]

**My template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame 
       Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <title>templates</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/media/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function update() {
            update_holder = $("#update_holder");
            most_recent = update_holder.find("div:first");
            $.getJSON("/live/updates-after/" + most_recent.attr('id') + "/",
                function(data) {
                    cycle_class = most_recent.hasClass("odd") ? "even" : "odd";
                    jQuery.each(data, function(){
                        update_holder.prepend('<div id="' + this.pk
                            + '" class="update ' + cycle_class
                            + '"><div class="timestamp">'
                            + this.fields.timestamp
                + '</div><div class="user">'
                + this.fields.user
                            + '</div><div class="text">'
                            + this.fields.text
                            + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div>'
                        );
                        cycle_class = (cycle_class == "odd") ? "even" : "odd";
                    }); 
                }

        );
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval("update()", 10000);
        })
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
  <div>
    <header>
      <h1>Live Update site</h1>
      <p>Содержимое обновляется автоматически</p>
    </header>
    {% if object_list %}
        <div id="update_holder">
            {% for object in object_list %}
                <div class="update {% cycle even,odd %}" id="{{ object.id }}">
                    <div class="timestamp">
                        {{ object.timestamp|date:"Y-m-d H:i:s" }}
                    </div>
          <div class="user">
          {{ object.user }}
          </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        {{ object.text|linebreaksbr }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>               
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <p>Нет обновлений</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url chat.views.saymessage %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
Введите текст сообщения: <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Update:
I figure out this problem, we need using natural_key(), and overrive this method in user manager class, add next code to models.py:

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def unatural_key(self):
        return self.username
    User.natural_key = unatural_key
```

And dont forget add argument `use_natural_keys=True` to serializers.serialize()

Comment: Do you know http://code.google.com/p/django-chat/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into [Natural Keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys). Natural keys allow you to specify what foreign key fields are serialized to. By constructing a primary key for your user, you can have the username in the serialization, instead of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this method to

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "[%s] %s by user: %s" % (
            self.timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            self.text,
            self.user.username
        )
```

But this is a dirty solution. Your view updates_after is very ugly. I would change updates_after. See a similar [view](http://tracpub.yaco.es/djangoapps/browser/inplaceeditform/trunk/inplaceeditform/views.py#L111)

Comment: big part of this code from book by Forcier J., Bissex P., Chun W. - Python Web Development with Django. I only added feature to add posts via index page, not from admin interface like that pronounced in book. I trying change self.user to self.user.username before i post this topic. I understand this code need refactoring, but i need to solve my problem with this code for understanding web development in django.